# Don't allow to maximize/show the application in QML

Tags: c++, linux, qml, qt5

I have an application in the QML/C++ that shouldn't be able to be maximized/showed by user. It should stay minimized whole time and when it receives a message from a server then it should maximize itself. Is it possible to do it in the QML? I was looking everywhere and I was not able to find anything similar to my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can start a window with `Window.Hidden` flag and show it when a signal received. Simple example:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id:  mainWindow
    visibility: Window.Hidden
    width: 400
    height: 300

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

        Timer {
            id: timer
            interval: 5000
            onTriggered: {
                console.log("signal received");
                mainWindow.visibility = Window.Maximized
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("window created");
            timer.running = true;
        }
    }
}
```

*Pay attention - you havn't test this code in Qml Viewer, it start its window anyway although QML window is hidden*

Comment: The problem is that this also hides the application from taskbar. The icon from taskbar disappears.

Comment: sure, you said the app must be not shown to user. if you want you app will be minimized just change it to `visibility: Window.Minimized`